# Does openssl need entropy for other purposes than generating the certificate and key?

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

Environment: Program is written in c/c++ for ubuntu 16.04 - no need cross platform solution.

I am programming a http network daemon, and i do not have /dev/urandom in the chroot, or any other entropy system inside the chroot.

I know that for generating the key/certificate, openssl definitely needs entropy. But once they are generated, and you are only using the key/certificate for encrypting client communications with your server - does the server daemon still need an entropy source?

Comment: I can't answer authoritatively, but [this person](https://www.sinodun.com/2018/01/using-openssl-from-inside-a-chroot/) seems to have run into issues in a chroot without `/dev/urandom`, from OpenSSL 1.1.1 onwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

It needs entropy for generating nonces, and for some asymmetric signature schemes.

It is probably possible to securely protect client communications without an entropy source - but I would be extremely nervous that one has missed a crucial part of the protocol which needs that bit of entropy.

Also, if you want perfect forward secrecy, you will need entropy to generate the temporary [EC]DH keys.

Your choices are:

- Consult an expert cryptographer to devise a protocol which requires no entropy (beyond the initial key).  Make sure they can construct/point to a proof that the protocol is secure.
- Get `/dev/urandom` in your chroot.
- As [James K Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/james-k-polk) suggested in a comment:  implement an entropy-gathering daemon in user space.  However you then probably need to consult an expert to determine if you have enough entropy.

---

Aside:  When you say "encrypting client communications" I presume you are actually using some sort of authenticated encryption scheme (for example AES+HMAC or AES-GCM).  If not, you probably have bigger problems than a lack of entropy.

If you have specific questions about whether your communication protocol needs additional entropy, https//crypto.stackexchange.com is full of people who would be happy to discuss the details of how to do it.

Comment: @mur: Sorry.  I don't understand what your point is.  You have a certificate - wonderful.  How are you going to select an IV to encrypt a packet with AES-GCM?  Your choices are "random choice" or "carefully select to ensure uniqueness" - doing the latter safely is hard.

Comment: Doesn't all this depend on the encryption scheme? For RSA and ECC there doesn't need to be entropy after generating keys... but for Elgamal entropy is needed because the mask changes all the time. Did I get this wrong?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist You don't use RSA/ECC to protect communications between server and client.  You use RSA/ECC (or [EC]DH) to protect a symmetric key which you use to protect the comms.  All the modes I know of, need an IV or nonce.

Comment: I know nothing about El Gamal (except that it exists).

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: RSA needs entropy for padding, ECC needs entropy for every use as well.

Comment: There is a third choice, implement an entropy-gathering daemon in user space. This is no panacea however, and like the first choice may require consulting an expert to analyze how much entropy is available.

Comment: @MartinBonner You answered my main question, but i think i lack expertise to understand what you mean on the rest of your answer. I am doing some further reading.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Padding? Could you explain?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: see [padding schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Padding_schemes)